# waf multi projects setup with integration area

Tags: waf

I have a folder `IntegrationArea` and a project, `main`, composed of 2 sub-projects, `a` and `b`, that looks like below:

```
IntegrationArea

main
  |
  a
    |
    wscript
  |
  b
    |
    wscript
  |
  wscript
```

Running `waf build` in `main/a` builds the artifatcs in `a/build`. Running `waf install` from the `main/a` installs the artifacts from `a/build` into the `IntegrationArea`. So, after the build, the artifacts are available for the build of `main/b`.

How can I write `main/wscript`so that running `waf build` from `main` results in the followings:

```
cd a; waf build; waf install
cd ../b; waf build; waf install
```

I would need `main/wscript` to contain something like

```
  bld.cmd=('build install')
  bld.recurse('a b')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you have something like:

```py
# wscript in main

def build(bld):
    bld.recurse(["a", "b"])
```

With:

```py
# wscript in a

def build(bld):
    bld(rule = touch, target = "a")
    bld.install_files("../integration", "a")

def touch(task):
    task.outputs[0].write("done a")
```

And:

```py
# wscript in b

def build(bld):
    bld(rule = touch, target = "b")
    bld.install_files("../integration", "b")

def touch(task):
    task.outputs[0].write("done b")
```

You can just go to main directory and start your install:

```
cd ~/main
waf install
```